# Difference between DIV as-is and a SPAN with display:block

Tags: html

Is `<div/>` different from `<span style="display:block" />` in any way?

They render just fine the same. Any semantic difference between the two?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Yes they are different.

Even though you style a span with `display: block` you still can't put block-level elements inside it:

```
<div><p>correct</p></div>
<span style="display: block;"><p>wrong</p></span>
```

The (X)HTML still has to obey the (X)HTML DTD (whichever one you use), no matter how the CSS alters things.

Comment: Is there any advantage to using a `span` over a `div` with `display:inline`, aside from the slightly lower number of characters that would be required?

Answer (score 14):

Here's an example where it makes a real difference (for valid code, at least):

```
<a href='example.com'>
    <span class='title' style='display:block;'>The title of the image is also a link</span>
    <img src="example.com/someimage.jpg"/>
</a>
```

That allows you to make your span a block level element and allows the image and span to highlight together when moused over.

A div would not be valid nested inside an a tag.

Comment: It makes the span _display_ as a block on a device that supports CSS, but it doesn't make it a block-level element - it remains an inline element. In this case, that's actually what you want, as the blockiness is purely for visual effect :-)

Comment: Yep. And that's the beauty of it. Though it does look less wonderful without the stylesheet.

Comment: It's a pity you discuss validity really, since your example provides a real, practical difference in browsers regardless of whether you care about HTML validity or not.

Answer (score 4):

A <div> is a block level element that has no specific semantics of its own, beyond defining a discrete block of content. A <span> is an inline element that has no specific semantics of its own, beyond defining a discrete segment of inline content.

You can use CSS to make a span display as a block, but there is absolutely no reason to do so EDIT: other than for purely visual effects, as Gabriel demonstrates; what I mean is that you shouldn't use CSS to try to coerce a span into having block-level significance in terms of document structure. Furthermore, if you do, your content will probably appear meaningless to a user without CSS, such as a blind user, or a search engine.

If it's a block, use a div. If it's part of inline content, use a span. Remember, CSS is about presentation alone; your markup still needs to be structured in a logical manner if your content is to be usable.

See http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#edef-DIV for the details.

Comment: The statement "absolutely no reason to do so" is blatantly untrue.

Comment: @Gabriel: I've just edited my comment to reference your example, where you demonstrate a good presentational use :-)

Answer (score 1):

Yes. They can contain different things and are allowed in different places.

They will also be rendered differently in environments where CSS is not available (e.g. in some email systems)