# Basic CSS Concepts

Tags: html, css

After discussion with some of my friends about css concepts, I have some questions to ask to you guys.

When do we use Id and class in css? and we have a conflict idea with Div and Span. When are Div and Span are used?

Any key to these questions?

Comment: None of the things you mentioned are CSS, they're all HTML concepts. Have a look at the HTML specification for extensive descriptions of the purposes of elements/attributes: http://www.w3.org/TR/html/

Answer (score 12):

A basic rule is that an ID may only exists once in the complete page. The ID is usually used to identify an object in your page. Most of the time you will use class in CSS.

A span is an in-line element, a div is a block element (by default, you can override this in your CSS). Spans are usually used inside a textblock to "mark" a piece of text. A div is used to group objects in a container.

Hope this helps you a bit.

Answer (score 6):

`div` is used as a section of a document. `span` is used to style individual parts of text. A key difference is that a div will insert a line break on either side.

However `div` and `span` are HTML not CSS.

You use `id` when there is one of an element and you need it to be uniquely identified.
You use `class` when there are multiple element which you want to apply the same stylings to.

Answer (score 4):

Div and span are HTML tags. You can stylise them using CSS, but as such, they are raw html elements.

Div is mainly used as a wrapper block, you can position, style and size it, then put content inside it, however it can also execute the function of span, if used as an inline-block.
Span is supposed to be used to highlight a bit of text within the paragraph tags, or to apply some specific styling to a bit of text that is between heading, list, anchor, (etc) tags.

(# - id) is used and should be used for a unique element that does not repeat on the page.

(. - class) is used for a set of elements that must inherit the same properties.

For example, form fields may have an id and a class, the ID will make them easy to highlight using javascript, while the class will apply the basic styles.

Answer (score 2):

[Should I use id or class?](http://css.maxdesign.com.au/selectutorial/advanced_idclass.htm)

The `div` element is a division of the web page. It's a block element.

The `span` element is used to enclose a span of text. It's an inline element.

Example:

```
<div>
   This is one part of <span>the page</span>.
</div>
<div>
   This is another part of <span>the page</span>.
</div>
```

You can use the styles `display:block` or `display:inline` to control the type of the elements. A block element can contain other block elements and inline elements. An inline element can contain other inline elements, but not block elements.

A link (the a tag) for example is an inline element, so you can put span tags in it, but not div tags. You can use the `display` style to make the link a block element and the elements inside it block elements. Even if you have made the link a block element using CSS, it should still only contain elements that are inline by default, even if you also turn those elements into block elements using CSS.

Answer (score 1):

An ID is a unique name given to an element on a page. An example would be 'product_98509'. A class is a non-unique reference to one or more elements on a page. For example 'product'. Then when using CSS you could reference all products with '.product {}' and a specific product with '#product_98509 {}'.

A  is a block-level element designed for boxes and containers. For example a header bar, a quote box, etc. A  is an in-line element usually used in text. For example someone's name in a paragraph, a price in a product description, etc.

Hope that helps a bit!

Answer (score 0):

The `id` attribute identifies **one** element on a page. It's used to specify a very specific element and you shouldn't switch the `id` around on elements unless you have a very good reason to do so. It's considered invalid to use the same `id` twice on one page.

The `class` attribute is an "adjective" on an element. It specifies something about the element that makes it different from other elements of the same type. For example, an `<ul>` element might be specific in that it is for a todo list, so you might specify it as `<ul class="todo">`. You can have multiple elements with the same class on the same page.

The purpose of `<div>` and `<span>` is similar in that they both specify generic content. Their difference lies in that `<div>` is for **block** content and `<span>` is for **inline** content. It's considered invalid to put block content in inline content, but the same is not true for the opposite (putting inline in block, or block in block for that matter.)

Answer (score 0):

Generally you would use ID when you have a specific (unique) element and class when you have many elements with the same styling.

Typically I'll use ID's to define "structural" elements in pages (main container, header, footer, sidebar, etc.) and use classes for everything else.

Elements with ID's are usually more convenient to access via javascript as well (although jQuery mitigates this a lot) so I'll often use ID's on elements that need to be manipulated by javascript, even if there is no styling associated with the ID.

Answer (score 0):

`id` uniquely identifies exactly one DOM element.  `class` identifies a set of related DOM elements.

`div` has [`display: block`](http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_class_display.asp) by default, and is generally used to demarcate some logical grouping of elements that should be in a block together.  `span` has [`display: inline`](http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_class_display.asp) by default, and is generally used to apply a style to sections of text.

Answer (score 0):

As Mike mentioned DIV and SPAN are HTML elements. Both are purely wrappers for content but as a general rule, span is used to wrap strings of text and divs are used to wrap blocks of content.

Think of span as an "inline" element to say apply a color to a word in a sentence vs. a div is a "block" where you might want to add a border, set a width and height etc.

Note: because CSS is flexible, you can make a div do anything a span can, and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest reading also this:

[Difference between DIV as-is and a SPAN with display:block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1142104/is-div-different-from-span-styledisplayblock)

Answer (score 0):

Here comes a little short description of **div** and **span** html tags.

The **span** and **div** tags are very useful when dealing with Cascading Style Sheets. People tend to use the two tags in a similar fashion, but they serve different purposes.

**div** also gives you the chance to define the style of whole sections of HTML. You could define a section of your page as a call out and give that section a different style from the surrounding text.

The **div** tag also gives you the ability to name certain sections of your documents so that you can affect them with style sheets or Dynamic HTML.

One thing to keep in mind when using the **div** tag is that it breaks paragraphs. It acts as a paragraph end/beginning, and while you can have paragraphs within a **div** you can't have a **div** inside a paragraph.

The **span** tag has very similar properties to the **div** tag, in that it changes the style of the text it encloses. But without any style attributes, the **span** tag won't change the enclosed items at all.

The primary difference between the **span** and **div** tags is that **span** doesn't do any formatting of it's own. The **div** tag acts includes a paragraph break, because it is defining a logical division in the document. The **span** tag simply tells the browser to apply the style rules to whatever is within the **span**.

Answer (score 0):

1) I use id when I know there will only be 1 on the page, I use class when there can be multiples.  Example, your header, there is only one, so I make that an id.

2) Divs/Spans - what everyone else said ... display block vs inline.

(This is just the way one lowly CSS developer does it).

Answer (score 0):

As stated this is really a a html question, although not one that you would normally come across unless you were using CSS (Why would anyone try and achieve perfect semantics, with a load of styling cluttering the document???)

**Div and Span**

Both div and span are html elements used purely to provide logical grouping of their contents. Div is a block element, and as such is a rectangular area with width, height, margins and padding. Span is an inline element, and so the above doesn't apply, but it can flow across multiple lines.

It should be noted that a  breaks any paragraph, so shouldn't be contained within on. It can, however, contain other paragraphs and block level elements without breaking itself.

**Class and ID**

An ID attribute is used to uniquely identify a given tag within an html document. You use the class attribute within CSS when you want to style one, and only one, section. The Class attribute describes the type of an attribute. For example consider the following:

```
<div class="widget"></div>
<div class="widget"></div>
<div class="widget"></div>
```